# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: python, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-saga

So I'm new to React and even though I've found multiple others having the same issue, I still haven't found the error in my code. Therefore I turn to you stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

I am learning, so I wanted to create a simple ReactJS application that handles a HTTP-request. After finishing the code I encountered the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object
    at exports.default (inherits.js?0578:21)
    at eval (app.js?71f7:22)`

The error persists even though I've tried a lot of different changes and I am fairly certain that it's related to imports/exports as this is what a lot of other sources tell me, although double-checking imports etc. hasn't yielded any results.

The code:

**app.js** ( handles the rendering of a simple button and should execute a simple GET request on click )

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { connect } from 'react-redux' 
import { createServerSagaRequest } from '../saga/serverSaga'
import { incrRequestAmount, requestSelector } from '../reducer/requestReducer'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    getRequestAmount: requestSelector.requests(state),
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    open: (url, data, action, method) => dispatch(createServerSagaRequest((url, data, action, method))),
    requests: () => dispatch(incrRequestAmount()),
  }
}


class App extends React {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  _buttonClick() {
    this.props.requests()
    this.props.open("http://mvctestproject.local/GetData", "TestDataFraGet", action, "GET")  
  }

  render(){    
    return (
      <button
      className="btn btn-default"
      onClick={this._buttonClick()}>{this.props.getRequestAmount()}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

**serverSaga.js** (my saga which can access the reducer and service)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { put, call, take, fork, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { callServer } from '../service/serverService'
import { incrRequestAmount, requestSelector } from '../reducer/requestReducer'

export function createServerSagaRequest() {return { type: CREATE_REQUEST }}


function* handleRequest(url, data, action, method, success){

  incrRequestAmount()

  return yield executeRequest(url, data, action, method, success)
}


function* executeRequest(url, data, action, method, success) {

    let response = yield call(callServer, url, method, data)
    let responseSuccess = response && response.Succeeded
    return 
}

export default function* serverSaga(){
  yield [
    fork(function*(){
      yield call (CREATE_REQUEST, handleRequest) 
    }),
  ]
}
```

**rootSaga.js** ( grouping sagas - in case I made more )

```
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects'

import serverSaga from './serverSaga'

export default function* rootSaga(){
  yield [
    fork(serverSaga)
  ]
}
```

**requestReducer.js** ( only function is to increment a variable after each request)

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'


export function incrRequestAmount() {return {type: 'INCR_REQUESTS'}}


const initialState = {
  requestAmount: 0
}

function requestReducer(state = fromJS(initialState), action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'INCR_REQUESTS':
      return state.updateIn(["requestAmount"], (requests) => requests++)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const requestSelector = {
  amount: state => state.requests.get('requestAmount')
}

export default requestReducer
```

**reducers.js** ( grouping reducers - in case i made more )

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import requests from './requestReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  requests,
})
```

**serverService.js** ( handles calls to the server (GET/POST)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export function callServer(url, bodyData, method){

  let methodType = method.toLowerCase()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let r;
    switch (methodType){
      case 'post':
        r = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)
        }
        break;
      case 'get':
        r = {
          method: 'GET'
        }
        break;
    }


    if (r) {

      console.log("URL: ", url)

      fetch(url, r)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Resp: ", url, response)
          return response.json()
        })


    }
  })
}
```

Comment: The only place I can see you using `super` is in your App's constructor, and it is a pointless constructor. What happens if you just remove it?

Comment: `class App extends React` should be `class App extends React.Component` (or `extends Component`, depending on your imports)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend `React.Component` to create a component, not `React` itself:

```
class App extends React {
```

should be

```
class App extends React.Component {
```

, or since you imported `Component` directly

```
class App extends Component {
```